# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, psql

I am trying to execute `01-plan_detail.sql` using the following code:

```
    with db.cursor() as c:
    logging.info('Combining results for 5500 long and short form to load plan details')
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
        '../resources/sql/01-plan_detail.sql'), 'rb') as io:
        c.execute(io.read())
        drain_notices(db, logging)
```

Every time I run this I get the following error on `execute()`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/00-laod_plan_detail.py", line 38, in <module>
    c.execute(io.read())
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "﻿drop"
LINE 1: ﻿drop table if exists lf5500 cascade
```

contents of 01-plan_detail.sql look close to this:

```
drop table if exists lf5500 cascade;
create temp table lf5500 as (
select * from from tableA lf
  left join tableB h
    on lf.ack_id = h.ack_id
)
distributed by (ack_id);

drop table if exists sf5500 cascade;
create temp table sf5500 as (
select * from from tableC sf
  left join tableD i
    on sf.bus_code = i.bus_code
)
distributed by (ack_id);

-- Combine results to create plan_detail table
drop table if exists f_5500_output_plan_detail cascade;
create table f_5500_output_plan_detail as (
select * from lf5500
union 
select * from sf5500
)
distributed by (ack_id);
```

If I execute the sql script separately, it run fine without errors. However, when I try to execute it using `psycopg2` from Python it is throwing the error.

Versions: `psql 8.2.15` | `python 3.6.0` | `psycopg2 2.6.1`

Can someone please take a look and help me figure out the issue?
Appreciate you help!